# Why can this javascript function not access a variable in the same class?

Tags: javascript, function, class, variables, public

For some reason, the player_controller instance variable created on the asterisked line cannot be called in the *update* function below. When I run this code, the second asterisked line (the console.log) will recognize and print the specified variable from player_controller to the console. However, when I try to use player_controller in the update function below (the double asterisked line), I get the error: "TypeError: this.player_controller is undefined."

Also note that if the bold line is commented out, the other lines (which have similarly created variables) run without errors.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

```
    function Engine(){
    var GRAVITY = 0.3;

    this.map_loader = new MapLoader();
    *this.player_controller = new PlayerController();*
    this.map = this.map_loader.load_next_map();
    *console.log(this.player_controller.keys_down.A);*

    this.update = function(){
        **this.player_controller.handle_input(this.map.player);**
        gravity(this.map.player);
        this.map.player.x += this.map.player.dx;
        this.map.player.y += this.map.player.dy;
        ...
        ...
```

edit: Didn't realize I couldn't do formatting in code blocks.

Here is a link to the app, if you view the web console while on this page you'll see the error I'm talking about piling up. http://lukescode.net/senior_project_game/main.html

Comment: You might want to create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to perfectly demonstrate your problem.

Comment: How is update being called? That's what determines the `this` value within the function.

Comment: update() is being called with `engine.update()` after creating an Engine object with `engine = new Engine()`.

Comment: Strange, that should work. Unfortunately I can't check your link right now (on iPad, no console).

Comment: Actually engine.update is called with `setInterval(engine.update, 1000/60)` sorry about that.

Comment: Then try `setInterval(function(){ engine.update() }, 1000/60)`. Callbacks to setInterval and setTimeout run with the global object as their `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I was making the call to Engine.update with `setInterval(engine.update, 1000/60)` which, as bfavaretto mentioned in a comment, changes 'this' to be something other than the engine in the update function. The solution was to call the function like this:

`setInterval(function(){return engine.update();}, 1000/60)`

which causes 'this' to properly refer to the object the update function belongs to instead of the window. Thanks to bfavaretto for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you create engine as

```
var engine = Engine();
```

instead of

```
var engine = new Engine();
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives a plethora more errors in places where I'm using the engine class, not to mention that I am generally looking to follow good object oriented practices in this project. Thank you for the suggestion though.